# how to display large list of data using reactJS as frontend and django rest framework as backend

Tags: django, reactjs

I am having large list of data of ingredients required for cooking. More than 3000+

I am using Django rest framework as the backend and ReactJs as frontend.

Each item in the list has a name, id, measurementunit, density in kg/ltr and cost/measurementunit

In Django i have created an api endpoint to supply the data in JSON format.

I want to display the data in a table format and with search filter on the top. Also at a time i want to show maximum 300 results.

Can someone guide me how to achieve this. Should i fetch all the list at a time or use pagination from django. Should i use seperate api for search or do it using reactjs on the frontend.

Presently i dont need any authorization in django. The data is for local use only.

Comment: pagination 1-2..-10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

3000 records is a lot to send down to the client in one chunk.  It is easier to develop against, but it doesn't scale well and is likely to create a measurable load time.  If you're OK with that, and you don't expect your data set to grow, then perhaps the pragmatic approach is to keep it as a big list... but it goes against best practices.

Either way, you likely don't want to show a giant 3k-row list to the user, so the UI will have some sort of pagination mechanism.  That might be "next", "previous" pages, or it might be infinite scrolling.  Either way, the data abstraction should be considering it as paged data.

**Paging API**
Assuming you decide to make your API support paging, you should use the backend framework's paging capabilities, like the [Django Paging API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/pagination/) or some other abstraction for your [REST API](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/).  There are lots of resources out there.

**Search**
The moment you decide to paginate the API, you are committing to handling search (filtering) on the backend as well.  The only way you can manage client-side filtering is if the client has access to all the data.  Since that isn't the case, you'll need to include a search filter in your data request.  Searching and pagination aren't mutually exclusive, so make sure your API supports both at the same time.  A common way to handle this would be like this:

```
http://yoursite.com/api/ingredients?page=5&page_size=100&search=carrot
```

**Client**
On the React side, you can build your own UI ([it is easy to do](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/03/14/react-pagination-example-with-logic-like-google)), or you can use a component which abstracts this for you, like [react-js-pagination](https://github.com/vayser/react-js-pagination) or [react-paginate](https://github.com/AdeleD/react-paginate).  The client component shouldn't really care if the API is paged or not.  Instead, it just notifies you when to display different records and the rest is up to you.

If you decide to keep everything in one big REST call, then you still need to slice the data out of your array to display.  If you paginate your API, then you can keep an instance cache on the client side of the pages you've received.  If you don't have the data, make the REST call to get it, and populate an array with the data.  That way, if a user goes forwards and then backwards, you aren't re-fetching.

**Conclusion**
I hope this helps a bit.  Enjoy :)

Comment: As my data will be keep increasing, so I should go with Django rest frame work pagination. and also search function from the api url. Thank you.

Comment: If i am searching from the DRF api, is there a way when i type for searching it shows suggestions.For that should i get the entire list from the api.

Comment: Typeahead search _can_ use the existing paged API, just always getting the first page with a small page set... though that may not be fast enough for your needs/UX.  Often a typeahead API is a tighter, more narrowly focused API which only returns the bare minimum necessary for the feature... so searching "ca" against a specialized API might return a list of strings... like `["carrot", "caper", "calamari", "canola oil"]`.  APIs like this will often use database indexing and caching to make sure they can keep up with the user typing.